# delete_via_redirect doing strange thigs in integration test (Test/Unit)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, integration-testing

Here is my test using Test/Unit:

```
test "signin and signout" do
  user = users(:alex)

  get signin_path
  assert_select 'h1', 'Sign In'

  # signing in...
  post_via_redirect signin_path,
                    email: user.email,
                    password: strong_pass
  assert_select 'a#current-user', "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}"
  assert_select 'a#signout', 'Sign Out'

  #signing out...
  delete_via_redirect signout_path
  assert_equal signin_path, path
  assert_select 'h1', 'Sign In'
  assert_select 'a#signin', 'Sign In'
end
```

And the result:

```
1) Failure:
   UserFlowsTest#test_signin_and_signout
   Expected at least 1 element matching "h1", found 0..
   Expected 0 to be >= 1.
```

As you can see in the begining after `get signin_path` I have my `h1` with signin text.
Also after
`delete_via_redirect signout_path`
my
`assert_equal signin_path, path`
is also ok.
But `assert_select 'h1'` can't find any `h1`.
And moreover I checked that
`assert_select 'a#signout', 'Sign Out'`
at this point is still true.

My methods:

```
def destroy
  sign_out
  redirect_to signin_url
end

def sign_out
  cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  self.current_user = nil
end
```

So method `destroy` redirected me to `signin_url`, but I still have signout-link and don't have any h1 (it's the most strange part).

I tested it with Capybara:

```
test "sign_out link" do
  user = users(:alex)

  sign_in user, capybara: true
  assert page.has_link?('Sign Out', href: signout_path)
  click_link 'Sign Out'
  assert page.has_selector?('h1', text: 'Sign In')
end
```

... and it passed.

So what's wrong with my test/unit test?

Answer (score 2):

Try `delete` method and then `follow_redirect!` method instead of delete_via_redirect. It worked in my similar case with patch_via_redirect method.